# Is there a way to print the number of iteration when running an apply function in R

Tags: r, iteration, apply

I run an apply-family function over a big dataset and so I wonder if there is a way to know how is going the job so far, how many elements got viewed so far, or something like this?

Comment: Check out the package [pbapply](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pbapply/pbapply.pdf) (progress-bar-apply)

Comment: `apply(..., function(x) {print(whatever); do_whatever()})`

Comment: @lukeA eh, not super impressed with pbapply, it adds a lot of overhead, compare the following: `tbp <- txtProgressBar(1,2000000)`, `x <- lapply(1:2000000,function(y) {setTextProgressBar(tpb,getTxtProgressBar(tpb) + 1);y + 1})`   vs `x <- pblapply(1:2000000,function(y) y + 1)` the latter takes minutes, the former takes maybe 10 seconds

Comment: Use forloop with flush.console(), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249317/r-display-a-counter-for-loops-across-one-display-line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to be alerted about the ongoing progress of a loop/lapply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832221/how-to-be-alerted-about-the-ongoing-progress-of-a-loop-lapply)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can consider creating a global counter, and specify when you want to print the progress, for example, you can print a notice whenever 10% of your data has been processed;

```
counter <- 0
data <- rnorm(100)
results <- sapply(data, function(x) { 
                  counter <<- counter + 1; 
                  if(counter %in% seq(0, length(y), 10)) 
                      print(paste(counter, "% has been processed"))})

[1] "10 % has been processed"
[1] "20 % has been processed"
[1] "30 % has been processed"
[1] "40 % has been processed"
[1] "50 % has been processed"
[1] "60 % has been processed"
[1] "70 % has been processed"
[1] "80 % has been processed"
[1] "90 % has been processed"
[1] "100 % has been processed"
```

Comment: Why not just `print(i)`?

Comment: The data passed to the function may be more specific than he wants to see. He just wants to know the progress, so it should be better to have a separate `counter`. I am just giving an example here, in reality, his data should be more complicated than `1:5` and may not necessarily reflect the progress.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a print statement to the function you are using like this

```
apply(mtcars,2, function(i) {print(i[1])
mean(i)})
```

Isn't pretty but does what you want